# global variables in node routes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, global-variables

in the code I have tried to make the id of the user a global variable after creating and saving to mongodb so as to use the id in the posts route but seems not to work.Any help on this?
      
     `newuser.save().then(function(user){
      if(user){
      id=user._id;
      req.session.user=user
      req.flash("success","post added")
         return res.redirect("/navashanti")

                 }}).catch((err)=>{
                     if(err){
                    console.log(err)}`

```
 `  app.get("/posts",function(req,res){
   user.findById().then(function(idresult){
    if(idresult){
    console.log(idresult)
    res.render("home",{idresult:idresult})
    }
    }    
             `
```

Comment: If saving is one API & `/posts` is different then why do you've to store `id` globally server side? What exactly are you trying to do here on both of these..

Comment: I want to get the id of the user saved into a global variable so as to get his details with the posts route

Comment: think of it this way, on a bigger picture your application would serve thousands of save user requests then which user's id would you store as global ?You need to pass-in id of user from front-end to retrieve his profile rather than storing it as global variable in server side & these two are independent calls so it wouldn't be feasible to do that. Just checking your scenarios to give you better real-time approach for this implementation, if you need to retrieve user profile immediately then from save response return user details or user_id back to UI which will be passed as input..

Answer (score 0):

you can define it with using GLOBAL or global.

```
global.id; // Declaration global variable - undefined
global.id= 1; //Global variable initialized to value 1. 
var userID =  global.id; // Using the global variable.
```

Comment: You can't put a single user's data in a global and expect that to ever work.  So, while the OP asked about globals, globals are the wrong approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT put data for one specific user into a global variable.

Even if you tried, it would be massively subject to timing and concurrency bugs.  Your server can serve many users.  If you put some data for userA into a global and then userB comes along, how does the server keep the right data with the right user.  If you're just using a single global, it doesn't.  It gets the data mixed up and one user gets the wrong data and another user's data is overwritten.  It's a disaster.  You cannot code servers this way.

Instead, data on a server has to be stored in a user-specific location so that each user's data is stored separately.  Globals are shared by all users so they will not work for this.  Some examples of a user-specific storage location are:

1. In a database record for that specific user
2. In a server-side session object that is uniquely for each specific user.
3. In a cookie which will be presented back to the server on future requests for that specific user.

If you want a specific coding suggestion for your specific issue, you'd have to show us an appropriate part of your code and describe exactly what problem you are trying to solve.  The code you have in your question so far is incomplete, improperly formatted (so it's difficult to read) and you do not fully describe what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the responses here, it's not a good idea to store the user id  as a global variable. I'm not too familiar with the capabilities of MongoDB but I think you could try using `sessions` as that allows you securely preserve user data for the duration of a user session.